# Is it possible to determine screen orientation in a native Windows 8.1 Desktop App?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime, clr, screen-orientation

I need to account for the different orientations a device can be in. Aka landscape, landscape flipped, portrait, or portrait flipped. My app is written in native C++ and is running on Windows 8.1 as a desktop app (cross platform is not a requirement in any way).

I know that I can determine if the device is in portrait or landscape using methods outlined by Microsoft here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812142.aspx

However, there's no way to discern between landscape and landscape flipped (or portrait and portrait flipped).

I could get exactly what I need by checking the [DisplayInformation.CurrentOrientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.currentorientation.aspx)   property but it's a WinRT API. Which means if I wanted to use it, my app would have to use CLR, which is a non-starter.

Also I'd really like to keep my app as a single executable and I don't think there's a clean way to do that and call managed APIs at the same time. But then again, I'm very inexperienced with native + managed code integration.

So, does anyone know of any way of figuring out display orientation using only native code in Windows?

Comment: So apparently I can't use DisplayInformation.CurrentOrientation because the DisplayInformation class is a Windows Store app-only class. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It should be noted that you do not need to do anything related to the CLR in order to use WinRT APIs in native desktop apps. You simply need to reference the WinMD files. That said, the DisplayInformation class is reserved for store apps only and will not function in desktop apps.

Comment: That's a great heads up. Thanks @zhuman-MSFT!

Comment: DisplayInformation works in desktop apps [starting in build 22621](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/windows.graphics.display.interop/nn-windows-graphics-display-interop-idisplayinformationstaticsinterop),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out. It's actually a lot easier than I thought. EnumDisplaySettings() doesn't populate the dmDisplayOrientation field in the DEVMODE struct, but [EnumDisplaySettingsEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does. So it's actually really easy :)

There's a good example [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/windows-8-desktop-app-desktop-rotation-sample-whitepaper).

Comment: It seems there's still an ambiguity because DEVMODE::dmDisplayOrientation values are DMDO_DEFAULT, DMDO_90, DMDO_180, and DMDO_270, while the ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE values are ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE/ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE_FLIPPED and ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_PORTRAIT/ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_PORTRAIT_FLIPPED. For example, in the case where DMDO_DEFAULT is a landscape mode, is DMDO_90 ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_PORTRAIT or is it ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_PORTRAIT_FLIPPED? That doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: This page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt614749.aspx seems to imply that DMDO_DEFAULT is always ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE and DMDO_90 is ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_PORTRAIT, etc. However, that conflicts with the dmDisplayOrientation documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Detect window SizeChanged in the XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="ClockCpp.MainPage"
      Loaded="Page_Loaded"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:ClockCpp"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Background="black"
      SizeChanged="Page_SizeChanged">
```

Then use is to toggle between portrait or landscape:

```
Boolean t46 = true;
void ClockCpp::MainPage::Page_SizeChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::SizeChangedEventArgs^ e)
{
        if (t46 == true)
        {
            t46 = false; // portrait
            timetext->FontSize = 120; // 2/3 of 180
            Othercontrols->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            t46 = true; // landscape
            timetext->FontSize = 180;
            Othercontrols->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed;
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also compare the screen height and width. If the width value was more higher then it's landscape and vice versa..

```
#include <windows.h>

int theScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN);
int theScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN);
if (theScreenWidth > theScreenHeight) 
    MessageBox(NULL,"Run in landscape.","Landscape",MB_OK);
else
    MessageBox(NULL,"Run in portrait.","Portrait",MB_OK);
```

Comment: This works, unfortunately, it does not differentiate between "landscape" and "landscape flipped" or "portrait" and "portrait flipped".